# grpc gives "INTERNAL: Connection closed with unknown cause"

Tags: microservices, grpc, grpc-java

We are using grpc for inter microservice communication. We are using grpc version: 1.2.0. For a particular test we keep seeing this error from one of the microservice:

```
io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INTERNAL: Connection closed with unknown cause
at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.blockingUnaryCall(ClientCalls.java:141)
at io.grpc.stub.ServerCalls$1$1.onHalfClose(ServerCalls.java:148)
at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor$TaskRunner.run(SerializingExecutor.java:152)
at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.toStatusRuntimeException(ClientCalls.java:227)
at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.getUnchecked(ClientCalls.java:208)
```

This happens only for the first few calls, or the first test that is trying to call another microservice using grpc. Subsequent calls are successful using the same code path are successful. All microservices are up and running.

Any ideas?

Comment: What are you getting if you set `GRPC_VERBOSITY=debug` and `GRPC_TRACE=all` on the server-side?

Comment: Where can I set these ?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: gRPC doesn't know what went wrong, and finding out can be _very_ time intensive, even with a debugger. That useless error should be [replaced with something more helpful](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/pull/3360) in the future 1.7 release. I'm not aware of any errors other than I/O errors that would trigger it yet be able to fix itself.

Comment: As workaround, I surrounded the call in a try catch block and in the catch block I retry the same call and it succeeds. Rest of the subsequent calls also succeed. How can I figure out if the connection is still active and if not then re-establish the connection?

Comment: Channels automatically re-connect. No need to manually re-establish the connection.

Comment: But without that change the call always fails on the first try. And every so often when there are no calls for a period of time.

Answer (score 2):

At least in my case this problem was a version mismatch between io.grpc (1.4.0) and io.netty (4.1.27.FINAL). I had to explicitly set the io.netty version to 4.1.11.FINAL in my build.gradle file and suddenly the exception was gone.

Unfortunately I could not find any information on which version of grpc works with which versions of netty.

I hope this helps you.